# How do I display data from my table in the magento frontend?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, frontend, model

I'd like to display data from the database table on my frontend screen, I'm trying this way:

**Teste/Cadastro/Block/Tabela.php**

```
<?php
class Teste_Cadastro_Block extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{

        public function getContent()
     {
        $cadastroModel = Mage::getModel('cadastro/cadastro');

        $collections = $cadastroModel->getCollection();

            foreach($collections as $collection)
        {
             print_r($collection->getdata(''));
        }
?>
```

**default/template/cadastro/cadastro.phtml**

```
...
            <div>
                    <?php echo $this->getContent(); ?>
            </div>
...
```

And in my **config.xml** I have the declared block.

Does this have to be done through a block or even an action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your model like that sample:

```
$cadastroModel = Mage::getModel('cadastro/cadastro');

$collections = $cadastroModel->getCollection()
               ->load();

foreach($collections as $collection){
         print_r($collection->getdata());
    }
```

Comment: It did not work, it only worked when I called directly in my phtml, but it is not the most correct way to do it, I will do all my phtml to analyze better

Comment: I think it's a mistake at the time of "pulling" or file to phtml, since it directly in phtml has effect, only that when I pull the file by `<? Php echo $ this-> getCollection (); ?>` It has no effect ..

Comment: I solved the error, in my xml I was setting as core / template and was not using my block "cadastro/tabela", thank you!